# Getting characters from a file in c

Tags: c, file-io, char

I wanted to get the characters of my text file. But I want it separately(spaces in the text separates the characters). This is my code for now.

```
main(){
    FILE *input_file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    char char_check;
    char *string;
    int i = 0;

    while ((char_check = fgetc(input_file)) != EOF ){
        string = "";//resets the string here
        while(number_check != ' '){
            string[i] = number_check;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
}
```

The expected outcome if text.txt has "This is a text." on it:
This\n is\n a\n text.

Comment: That's not how strings work in C. You need to *allocate* the string to hold the expected number of characters, and possibly reallocate it if the input exceeds this expectation. See functions `malloc()` and `realloc()`. Get a good book on C that explains these topics.

Comment: you might want to define `number_check` somewhere before using it... or the compiler might complain (you *did* enable all compiler warnings before asking here, didn't you?). Also `""` is a string literal, you can't change it.

Comment: Your code looks really unrelated to what you seem to want. Could you post an example file and your expected outcome? For example, what would you want to have printed, if the file had `This is a text` in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to your last edit as a response to my request, let's examine what modification you have made to the original text to obtain your desired result. The original text is:

```
    This is a text.
```

And you've turned that into:

```
    This\n is\n a\n text.
```

I hope that this is as clear to your eyes as it is to mine; but there, you have inserted a new-line `'\n'` right before each occurrence of space `' '`. So, you could do exactly that by;

- getting a character right before cycle in a `while` loop, a loop that would end when the file ends
- `if` the acquired character is a `' '`, then printing a `'\n'`
- after that printing the acquired character, no matter what it was

Like this:

```
...
    while ( ( char_check = fgetc( input_file ) ) != EOF ){
        if ( char_check == ' ' ) {
            printf( "\n" );
        }
        printf( "%c", char_check );
    }
...
```

There were several problems with your code that would cause it to not work at all. You are using a variable named `number_check` that you haven't initialized. You are trying to assign values to `string[i]` for any `i`, you may not do that.

To do that, you first need a space. To have the space, you can;

```
// initialize string as an array
// which will automatically allocate memory for you to use
char string[123];

// manually allocate a memory to use
char * string;
string = malloc( 123 );

// or better
string = malloc( 123 * sizeof( char ) );

// or even better
string = malloc( 123 * sizeof( * string ) );

// but if you use malloc, remmeber to use free, to free the memory after using it
// !! only if you use malloc/calloc/realloc !!
free( string );
```

Forget about the assignment `string = "";`, it won't empty out an array, nor grant you an empty array, as would like to have.

Just reset `i` back to `0` before starting each loop and overwrite the previous characters.

Appending a sequence of characters (string) with a `'\0'`, which is simply zero, is a must. If you don't do that, `printf( "%s", string );` won't know when your string will end. You may think of that zero, the terminating zero, as a full-stop to your whole string.

Anyway, I think this much information should suffice. Let's re-write your original code to have it work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     // <-- included stdlib.h for malloc

int main( ){
    FILE *input_file = fopen( "text.txt", "r" );
    char char_check;
    char *string;
    int i = 0;

    string = malloc( 321 * sizeof( *string ) );     // <-- allocated memory for string

    while ( ( char_check = fgetc( input_file ) ) != EOF ){

        i = 0;      // <-- resetting i back to zero

        while ( char_check != ' ' && char_check != EOF ){   // <-- added an EOF check
            string[i] = char_check;
            i++;
            char_check = fgetc( input_file );   // <-- added this, to obtain next
        }
        string[i] = '\0';               // <-- appended with zero, important

        printf( "%s\n ", string );      // <-- added a space after the \n
    }

    free( string );     // freed the allocated memory after use

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has quite solved the problem. Its executing but there are random characters coming out

Comment: @user3440111 For which version are you talking about? Both work out on my end here. Keep in mind that the first one, with the `printf( "%c", char_check );`, has a single `while` loop; while the second one, with the `printf( "%s\n ", string );`, has two nested `while` loops.

Comment: First one works, second one doesn't and i really wanted to use the second one because i still need the strings.

Comment: I think the problem is the resetting of the string. If there are only two-character-string after a three-character-string the character would be copied. Example, text file has "dg haa hgB jf ghj ahg". The output for this will be "dg\n haa\n hgB\n jfB\n ghj\n ahg\n"

Comment: @user3440111 I have copied the last code above, compiled and executed it, and the result isn't as you claim: [**picture proof**](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/081/3/0/no_by_thoappelsin-d7b5nww.png) What are the differences on your code, than in mine?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to print out the file character by character with spacing, you could simply print out each character followed by a space.

```
main(){
    FILE *input_file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    int number_check;

    while ((number_check = fgetc(input_file)) != EOF ){
        printf("%c ", number_check);
    }
}
```